# How can I shorten this if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this function for checking which way we are facing when traveling through a coordinate system, by looking at how the values in a tuple increase, or decrease in comparison to the next value in a list of waypoints. Looking at the code, it feels convoluted and clumsy:

```
a.facing = self.direction(a.travel_list[0], a.travel_list[1])

def direction(self, start, end):
    s_width = start[0]
    s_height = start[1]
    e_width = end[0]
    e_height = end[1]
    # check directions
    if s_height < e_height:
        if s_width < e_width:
            return 'right'
        elif s_width > e_width:
            return 'up'
        else:
            return 'up_right'

    elif s_height > e_height:
        if s_width < e_width:
            return 'down'
        elif s_width > e_width:
            return 'left'
        else:
            return 'down_left'

    elif s_height == e_height and s_width < e_width:
        return 'down_right'
    else:
        return 'up_left'
```

The return values are adjusted to be rotated one step clockwise. My question is, how can we change the code to make the function shorter and more efficient?

Edit: Note that movement can only happen in the 8 directions specified.

Comment: Can `start` and `end` ever be equal? You don't seem to handle that case correctly. Also I think ` elif s_height == e_height and s_width < e_width:` could be `elif and s_width < e_width:` because by this point it's already been determined `s_height == e_height`. Your code is not bad, a little verbose. @AshRj is probably better. I'm working on a version myself.

Comment: @jimhark I only call this function when moving around, so there is no need to change the facing direction otherwise.

Comment: I just noticed (by testing) that the strings you produce are, um, non-intuitive. @AshRj's generated results make more sense to me, but maybe I don't fully understand your requirements (or maybe definitions). So can you explain why `if s_height < e_height and s_width < e_width return 'right'`? I would have guessed `up_right`.

Comment: It'll make sense if you see the context. The logic is calculating actual data from moving around in the system, but the strings represent what is subsequently drawn to the screen, and to make it easier for me to mentally keep track of what sprites to use at different times during the program. To see what I mean, look at this previous question I posted some time ago, which includes pictures of the program in action: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/pygame-performance-issue-for-many-images/

Comment: I've posted my answer it's short, a little ugly, and slow (doh!). There's nothing wrong with the approach taken in your original code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary based on the *cmp()* return values:

```
def direction(self, start, end):
    return table[cmp(start[0], end[0]), cmp(start[1], end[1])]
```

Build the dictionary to summarize your current logic:

```
table = {
    (-1, -1): 'right',
    (-1, 1):  'up',
    (-1, 0):  'up_right',
       ...
}
```

If you're using Python 3, you will need define your own *cmp()* function as:

```
cmp = lambda x, y:  -1 if x < y else 1 if x > y else 0
```

Answer (score 2):

On changing your function a little, you can return a list of the directions with a simple function definition :

```
def direction(self, start, end):
    delta = (end[0] - start[0], end[1] - start[1])

    s = []

    if delta[1]>0 : s.append("up")
    elif delta[1]<0 : s.append("down")

    if delta[0]>0 : s.append("right")
    elif delta[0]<0 : s.append("left")

    return s
```

Here s will contain either 0, 1 or 2 members depending on direction of travel. The list will be empty in the case of no movement.

If you specifically need the return value in the format you specified, then you can simply extract the values from the list and parse as needed.

---

I dont completely understand your need for the clockwise shift, but if thats not changeable then i would suggest using some shorter/simpler values as placeholders initially and then using a dictionary to handle both the substitution of the placeholders with the desired text as well as the clockwise shift.

Comment: Your logic for mapping `start` and `end` makes sense, but doesn't match the original question (which doesn't make sense, but may be required for some reason).

Comment: The original question has: `s_width = start[0]; s_height = start[1]; e_width = end[0]; e_height = end[1]`. So [0] is x (width) and [1] is height. (Though it's not clear the rest of the code is consistent with this.) Do you have your axis reversed?

Comment: @jimhark Yes i had realised the error as soon as i closed my browser, but was busy so could not change it. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Get the y and x distances

Step 2: Call atan2(x, y) to get the angle ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2 )

Step 3: Divide by pi/4 and round to the nearest integer to get a value between -4 and 4

Step 4: Now you can do a case/switch, each of those values will be a different cardinal direction (-4 and 4 will be the same direction, for example both east)

EDIT: I just realized this only works if you consider e.g. 10 degrees higher than east still east. XD Let me think of a better one...

EDIT 2: Ok, try this:

Step 1: Make a tuple of two values

Step 2: Value 1 = cmp(x1, x2)

Step 3: Value 2 = cmp(y1, y2)

Step 4: Do a lookup in a table of tuples to directions (e.g. 0,1 is north, 0,-1 is south, 1,1 is northeast and so on) and return the result

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the movement is 8-way only. I'm updating the OP now.

Comment: It was my fault, I was so excited to use atan2 that I forgot it didn't fulfill the problem definition. LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and` operators:

```
a.facing = self.direction(a.travel_list[0], a.travel_list[1])

def direction(self, start, end):
    s_width, s_height, e_width, e_height = start[0], start[1], end[0], end[1]
    # multiple assignments
    # check directions
    if s_height < e_height and s_width < e_width:
        return 'right' 
    elif s_height < e_height and s_width > e_width:
        return 'up'
    elif s_height < e_height: # this will get executed if the top two are false
        return 'up_right'     # its similar to using the `else` in a nested conditional
    elif s_height > e_height and s_width < e_width:
        return 'down'
    elif s_height > e_height and s_width > e_width:
        return 'left'
    elif s_height > e_height:
        return 'down_left'
    elif s_height == e_height and s_width < e_width:
        return 'down_right'
    else:
        return 'up_left'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your original code is correct, then there is something about your mapping that I don't understand. Assuming start is (width, height), as you call it, or (x, y) as I use below, and assuming x increases to the right and y increases up (the usual case in mathematics, but your requirements seem to be a little different), here's a concise way to tell where end is relative to start (using your set of string names):

```
DIR_STR_LIST  = ("up", "down", "right", "left")

def direction3((sx, sy), (ex, ey)):
    conds = (sy < ey, ey < sy, sx < ex, ex < sx)
    istr = DIR_STR_LIST.__iter__()
    return '_'.join([istr.next() for c in conds if c or not istr.next()])
```

The `or not istr.next()` is needed to advance the iterator when `c` is false.

While this *is* concise, it's a little uglier than I'd like. I thought it *might* perform better then the original code (because list comprehensions are **fast**), but this is a case where simplicity is better for performance. The original code is 5 times faster (ouch!).